# Preview Pane style - List view breaking after modifying display columns

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list-view, ootb

I'm having an issue with my list views, when using the preview pane style. I have views that worked perfectly, however if I modify the view to change the selected display columns, the preview pane no longer shows the title field from which to hover and display the list item. Are there required fields that the preview pane needs to work? I'm not removing the title field from display.

I want to keep the title field, and the columns I have removed from display are all empty (i.e. not used in the list form). I can change the preview panel to show list items by hovering over the blank space where the title field used to be, it's like it's hidden from view. See below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have had instances of list views "getting corrupted", meaning they just stop functioning properly. I can usually resolve the issue by deleting the view and rebuilding. Verify the view after each change you make to identify what is breaking it. Sorry I don't have a concrete answer for you. Let us know what you found to be the cause.